# Passing multiple arguments to C function within Python

Tags: python, arguments, ctypes

Let's say I have a c library that manipulates a world somehow.

I want to use this library with python. I want to be able to write simple python scripts that represent different scenarios of world management.

I have functions that create and destroy a world:
void* create(void);
int destroy(void* world);

Here is some python code:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('manage_world.so')

_create = lib.create
_create.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

_destroy = lib.destroy
_destroy.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p,]
_destroy.restype = ctypes.c_int

def create_world():
    res =  _create()
    res = ctypes.cast(res, ctypes.c_void_p)
    return res

def destroy_world(world):
    return _destroy(world)

new_world = create_world()
print type(new_world)

print destroy_world(new_world)
```

Now I want to add functions like:
int set_world_feature(void* world, feature_t f, ...);
int get_world_feature(void* world, feature_t f, ...);

The thing is that in my python wrapper I don't know how to pass variously multiple arguments.

Because sometimes set_world_feature() is called with 3 or 4 arguments.

In Python again:

```
def set_world_feature(world, *features):
    res = lib.set_world_feature(world, *features)
    return world_error[res]
```

How to fix this in order for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
def create_world():
    return _create
```

You don't call `_create`, so `create_world` returns the function pointer. If you want the pointer to your world instance you should write instead:

```
def create_world():
    return _create()
```